# htaccess browser language redirection

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^(en|de)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^%1.domain.dev$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* http://%1.domain.dev [R,L]
```

This code causes redirection loop error. I've debug second condition, which should prevent this, and both HOST and right side seems to be identical. This is 20th version or so, I run out of ideas.

Comment: Add a "$" at the end of your both  conditions.

Comment: Did not help, I've updated second condition as previous version wasn't redirecting at all.